# Text file import to dataframe with pandas: Data in Blocks

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm kinda new at using pandas, since I've done most of my data analysis usually with R.

Data format can be seen from this link where I got my data from:
https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Movies.html

There are also HTML tags in the review/text attribute as well. So I'm thinking I should get rid of those too when I perform text sentiment analysis on it.

[Data snippet of a record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YRvo.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you please clarify what your question is?

Comment: How can I import the textfile from the link above as a dataframe using pandas?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Would you mind posting a snippet of the file, since it's a 4GB download. :)